# Retrieving data via awk and openssl

Tags: awk, openssl

I am using **openssl** to encrypt data in a file.

In the process of assigning the data in that file to shell variables, I am dynamically decrypting the file and attempting to use **awk** to parse it into variables.

```
$ myuser=$(echo | awk '{print $1}' | openssl aes-256-cbc -in encrypted -pass file:../password.txt -d) 
$ echo $myuser 
Bruce-Wayne Batman 0.0.0.0
```

I should just be echoing `Bruce-Wayne` but somehow my **awk** instruction is not working as well as I expect.

Can anyone offer an insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have your piping muddled:

```
$ myuser=$(openssl aes-256-cbc -in encrypted -pass file:../password.txt -d | awk '{print $1}')
```

That is you want the first field in `Bruce-Wayne Batman 0.0.0.0` which is effectively:

```
echo "Bruce-Wayne Batman 0.0.0.0" | awk '{print $1}'
```

Doing `echo | awk '{print $1}'` is the same as doing `echo` you are piping the output of `echo` *(which is nothing)* into `awk`.

Comment: Nope the data flows from left to right `:]` please consider accepting this answer if it was useful.

Answer (score 1):

```
myuser=$(openssl aes-256-cbc -in encrypted -pass file:../password.txt -d | awk '{print $1}')
```

You don't need the echo and you should awk the output of the openssl command.  I don't have your password.txt so I just created a clear text version and replaced your openssl command with cat password.txt.  Using your order, with the echo, I got your outpupt.  Using my order, and without the echo I got Bruce-Wayne.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your answer